# bitbucket: setup ssh keys but still asking for password

Tags: git, bitbucket

so I want to avoid typing my password all the time when synching my personal repos so I setup SSH keys on my 2 boxes.

On the first box, it works fine. But on the 2nd one, it still keeps on asking me for the password when synching repos.

I've deleted deleted my working folder (which includes user files and .git folder) and started again from scratch using git clone and even git clone asks for the password.

**I've setup SSH keys previously for at least 10 work-related repos and never had this issue.** But it's only now I started using git/bitbucket for my personal stuff.

Any ideas what I've done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please add the "git clone" command you have used.

Comment: You can also test your SSH connection from the second box with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` - it should return your Bitbucket username if the keypair is set up properly on both ends.

Comment: @JimRedmond I'll that tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the url used during clone. If you have used 'https' it will always ask for password. Instead use the one mentioned under SSH in overview screen of your repo in Bitbucket.

It is like:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:....
```